# Create button with click event Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have the following item.xml -

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/[id required here for click event.]"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using this layout template I am creating multiple items in the code behind -

```
    public Item(string title, Button btn)
    {
        Text = title;
        Button = btn;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView)
    {
        var item = Items[position];
        var view = convertView;

        var contentItem = (Item)item;
        view = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListViewContentItem, null);

        var title = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle);
        var btn = view.FindViewById<Button>([button id??]);

        title.Text = contentItem.Text;
        btn = contentItem.Button;

        return view;
    }
```

My understanding is that id's have to be unique, so how can I create buttons  with unique id's so that I can access their click events?

My code would have to be able to handle the creation of multiple Items each with their own buttons.

Comment: Is the button at the end a dynamic button as well or will that one be static

Comment: And in according to which condition will these show up?

Comment: @G.hakim sorry I have just realised my xml was confusing I have since amended! Hopefully now you can see each item only require ONE button, however I do not know what id to assign it or how to hookup a click event due to the fact there are going to be multiple items each with thier own button.

Comment: Check my answer below, let me know if it solves your query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simple you use id the same way as you used for TextView

So your button would look something like this:

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/buttonId"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now in your click event, you can use the Position Parameter to find out which element of the list is receiving the click even at eg:

```
  var btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonId);
  btn.Clicked+= (s,e)=>
  {
    if(position==someValue)
    {//Code}
    else
    {//Code}
  };
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this (tonight) and mark as correct once implemented.

Comment: Sure no problem, let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in GetView method :

```
 var btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonId);
    btn.Tag=position;
    btn.SetOnClickListener(this);
```

after implement "View.IOnClickListener" in your adapter and override Onclick method

```
public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.Id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.buttonId:
                   //Write code here
                    break;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And for you activity:

```
Button btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
btn.Clicked+= btn_click;

private void LiveLeadSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Your implementation
}
```